# How do you set an Expandable Recycler View's parent views to be expanded by default

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I have an expandable recycler view, and it is displayed when my activity is started. However by default the parent views are collapsed.

I have tried setting setExpanded(true) inside my parent view holder like so:

```
public PersonParentViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mPersonTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_list_item_person_title_text_view);
    mParentDropDownArrow = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_list_item_expand_arrow);
    setExpanded(true);
}
```

But that does not seem to help.

This is the creation of the ParentViewHolder

```
@Override
public PersonParentViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.person_parent_layout, viewGroup, false);

    return new PersonParentViewHolder(view);
}
```

Here is where the recycler view is created if that helps at all

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_fragment_layout, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.person_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    updateUI(view);

    return view;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was using a deprecated version of BigNerdRanch's ExpandableRecyclerView. I was able to expand the ParentView by updating to the latest version of the ExpandableRecyclerView. To do so:

add `compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.1.1'` to the dependencies of the app gradle, and install the necessary packages.

Then on the your Parent objects for the expandable list that implement `ParentListItem` you need to override the `isInitiallyExpanded` like this

```
@Override
public boolean isInitiallyExpanded() {
    return true;
}
```

This was standard as of version 2.0.0 or so.

The complete tutorial for the latest version (2.1.1) can be found here.
http://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/

Hope this helps!